# Schauder basis for Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, schauder-basis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces that are known to have Schauder bases.

If $x_i$ is a Schauder basis for $X$, and $T:X \to Y$ is a linear homeomorphism, is it true that $Tx_i$ is a Schauder basis for $Y$?

It seems obvious that the answer is yes but I am only confused about the role of "unconditional convergence" here...

Comment: Take $X = Y = \mathbb{R}$ and let $T(x) = x - 1$, then $T$ is a homeomorphism that sends the basis $\{1\}$ to $\{0\}$ which is not a basis. I suspect you meant to impose stronger conditions on $T$.

Comment: He probably means that $T$ is an isomorphism of Banach spaces.

Comment: @Christopher A. Wong: well isomorphism of Banach spaces would make it trivial. My guess is that the OP meant is isomorphism of $X$ and $Y$ as vector spaces, but why not let the OP tell us.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong: You mean a linear isometric isomorphism? I guess that $T$ is assumed to be a linear isomorphism that is also a homeomorphism (not necessarily an isometry), because if $T$ is isometric then the answer is rather easy.

Comment: @RobArthan I should have said linear homeomorphism. By that I mean a continuous map with continuous inverse. It is not isometric however.

Comment: Yes, it's true. If we transport the norm of $Y$ to $X$ via $T$, the assumption that $T$ is an isomorphism of topological vector spaces (or even of Banachable spaces) says you got an equivalent norm. So the question is: "Is being a Schauder basis a topological property or norm-dependent?" The answer is: topological.

Comment: Daniel is right.  And BigUser should try to prove it.

Comment: Thank you, I will do that.